# Angular2 refresh page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having trouble getting Ng2 to refresh the page.
The purpose of this is because i have a CRUD system, and when you enter a new entry i want the page to refresh if it is succesful. The reason for this is because the table is populated via code entries such as `{{ studentAssign.assID[0]._id }}`
However when I submit a new entry of assID it then joins the array as `studentAssign._id` and then provides a blank entry, and messes up 'editing' and 'delete' function.

My create function

```
submitCreate(studentAssign) {
        this.authHttp.post("/api/student-assignment/", JSON.stringify(studentAssign), this.options).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.studentAssigns.push(studentAssign); // the response contains the new item
                this.sendInfoMsg("item added successfully.", "success");
                // workaround to reset the form values
                this.workaround = false;
                setTimeout(() => this.workaround = true, 0);
            },
            err => console.log(err)
        );
    }
```

I have tried numerous things to force a page refresh. I.e. `this.router.renavigate();` and `this.router.navigate(['/Student-Assign']);` and also `this.zone.run(() => {});` ... zone for NgZone (re-renders the component), but none have worked.

Is there something I am missing? Or is it easy to create an 'assID' array instead to avoid having to page refresh?

**Edit ngFor code**

```
<tr *ngFor="let studentAssign of studentAssigns">
                    <td style="text-align:center;"><div tooltip="{{studentAssign.assID[0].assignName}}" tooltipPlacement="top" tooltipTrigger="mouseenter">{{ studentAssign.assID[0]._id }}</div></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;"><div tooltip="Email: {{studentAssign.studentID[0].email}} Name: {{studentAssign.studentID[0].firstName}} {{studentAssign.studentID[0].lastName}}" tooltipPlacement="top" tooltipTrigger="mouseenter">{{ studentAssign.studentID[0]._id }}</div></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" (click)="toggleEdit(studentAssign)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="submitRemove(studentAssign)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

It comes in an array as i am populating it from mongoose, raw JSON:

> {"_id":3,"__v":0,"studentID":[{"_id":"1240681","email":"mrjakegroves@googlemail.com","lastName":"Groves","firstName":"Jakey","__v":0}],"assID":[{"_id":"As
>   1","assignName":"Cwk","__v":1,"modInsID":[13]}]}

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Angular2 change detection doesn't check array or object content for changes, only the object identity. `*ngFor` itself checks the array content for changes and if there are bindings Angular CD checks these bindings if there are changes. Therefore there shouldn't be any need or any workaround or hack. Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Next reply tomorrow. Time for bed :O

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for your reply ... and no errors in your console. And well it registers a new entity in the array as i have this code `{{ studentAssigns.length ? studentAssigns.length : 0 }}` and the increases the amount in the array, it is just that when i add new entity it doesn't store it as `studentAssign.assID[0]._id` it stores it as `studentAssign._id` which is not what i want, I need it to be stored as `studentAssign.assID[0]._id` or refresh the page so it populates the array, if that makes sense? thanks for reply anyway :)

Comment: That doesn't sound related to Angular. That sounds more like an issue with keeping your data in a consitent form.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer so are you saying I should have two api links that 'get' ? i.e. 1: will not populate the relationships and keep it as `studentAssign._id` and then have a seperate get request that populates it such as :`studentAssign.assID[0]._id` ?

Comment: Actually I don't know why you get the same data in different forms. I think you should ensure in "some" way to have them in a compatible form and always use the same form or if this is not possible transform it to the required form before adding it to the array.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer reading what you just said just popped the solution into my head ... I can trasnform it by when I create the object to database, I can then populate it and send it back to Ng2, thus it will be in the same format :D! Thanks for your time man!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
res => {
  this.studentAssigns.push(studentAssign); 
  this.studentAssigns = this.studentAssigns.slice();
}
```

I would need to see more code (do you use `*ngFor` to bind the array) for better suggestions.

Comment: Thankyou for your quicky reply, i added extra code and raw JSON format for you in the main post. It comes from the mongoDB with arrays as i populate the relationships